# only some methods accessible in jar file

Tags: java, jar

I got a java class from which I created a jar file to access the class in another project.

the class looks like this

```
public class RunMain {

    private ArgumentObject argObject = null;
    private String outputFile = null;
    private SimObject simObject = null;

    public RunMain() {
    }

    public RunMain(String file) {
        outputFile = file;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new RunMain().doMain(args);
    }

    public void testMethod(){

    }

    public void blaMethod(){

    }

    public SimObject getResults(){
        return simObject;
    }

    public void doMain(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // do some stuff

    }  

    // write term and doc vectors to bin files
    void writeVectorStore() throws Exception{

        // do some stuff
    } 
}
```

My problem is, that when I now wanna access the methods in another project I can only call the main method or the doMain method.

```
RunMain run = new RunMain();
run.doMain(arguments);
```

this works fine

```
SimObject simObject = run.getResults();
```

this is marked red with "The method getResults() is undefined for the type RunMain"

Does someone have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I have two ideas:

1. The jar file contains an earlier version of the compiled class.
2. You use an earlier version of the jar file.

But it is not possible that only some public methods of a class are accessible a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to check...

1. Make sure the project using this jar file doesn't have its own version of class RunMain on the classpath.  It will "override" RunMain in the jar file.  If there is a local version of the class thant doesn't have the method getResults(), well there's your compiler error.
2. If you've been working on the .jar file for awhile.. better re-build it to make sure the code in there is the latest version.  It's possible you created the jar, then added a method, but didn't recreate the jar file.  Then make sure the new jar file is being referenced by your project.

Comment: I guess 2. sounds most applicable. What I already did, was deleting the old jar file in the project and from the hard drive, creating a new one with a different name and then included it. but still it seems to have the old version somewhere. I don't find a way to get it to use the new jar file..